# Can we change the primary key for the all the migration which is in production?

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to change the table primary key id to uuid. But the problem is data is already on production. There is a option to re write the whole migration but then we lost the data which we already have.

Also the table has too many association with each other. So is there a way to handle this situation?

We are using phoenix and elixir with postgres for this.

Comment: Doing that with little down time is difficult, particularly with the foreign keys. Are you certain you need to do that?

Comment: Yes. But the foreign key are also I'm concerned about.

Comment: I was questioning the need for UUID in general.

Comment: Yeah we need that

Comment: Usually because it's unique across every table, every database and server

Answer (score 2):

Yes. One might accomplish the task with several steps, some executing raw SQL against the database.

- migration 1 creates the new column in the database, unique, not null, type `:uuid` (normal migration) *and* fills it with unique values (using [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) UUID generator, for instance)
- migration 2 uses [`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#query/4) to reassign the primary key in the table¹
- migration 3 updates all other tables referring this one, by deleting the foreign key *then* updating values from `id` to `uuid` and *then* creating a new foreign key pointing to `uuid`²

---

¹ somewhat along the following lines (untested)

```elixir
defmodule MyRepo.Migrations.ChangeFK do
  def up do
    MyRepo.query("""
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY foo_pkey_idx ON foo(id);

    ALTER TABLE foos
      DROP CONSTRAINT foo_pkey,
      ADD CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX foo_pkey_idx;
    """)
  end

  def down do
    raise "unreversible"
  end
end
```

² somewhat like

```elixir
defmodule MyRepo.Migrations.AlterFK do
  def up do
    MyRepo.query("""
    ALTER TABLE bars DROP CONSTRAINT foo_pkey;

    UPDATE bars SET foo_id = (SELECT uuid FROM foos WHERE id = foo_id);

    ALTER TABLE bars
      ADD CONSTRAINT foo_pkey
      FOREIGN KEY (foo_id)
      REFERENCES foos (uuid);
    """)
  end

  def down do
    raise "unreversible"
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm little confused about the 2nd and 3rd migration. Can you give us a small example?

Comment: also do we need to use adapter? there is a execute function which can implement sql query

Comment: Updated the answer with _untested_ code. I dunno what “execute function” means.